# Jython output formats, adding symbol at N:th character

Tags: python, regex, jython

I have a problem that probably is very easy to solve. I have a script that takes numbers from various places does math with them and then prints the results as strings.

This is a sample

```
type("c", KEY_CTRL)
LeInput = Env.getClipboard().strip() #Takes stuff from clipboard
LeInput = LeInput.replace("-","") #Quick replace
Variable = int(LeInput) + 5 #Simple math operation

StringOut = str(Variable) #Converts it to string
popup(StringOut) #shows result for the amazed user
```

But what I want to do is to add the "-" signs again as per XXXX-XX-XX but I have no idea on how to do this with Regex etc. The only solution I have is dividing it by 10^N to split it into smaller and smaller integers. As an example:

int 543442/100 = 5434 giving the first string the number 5434, and then repeat process until i have split it enough times to get my 5434-42 or whatever.

**So how do I insert any symbol at the N:th character?**

OK, so here is the Jython solution based on the answer from Tenub

```
import re
strOut = re.sub(r'^(\d{4})(.{2})(.{2})', r'\1-\2-\3', strIn)
```

This can be worth noting when doing Regex with Jython:

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. **So r"\n" is a two- character**
>   **string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string**
>   **containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python**
>   **code using this raw string notation.**

Here is a working example
http://regex101.com/r/oN2wF1

Comment: What if the number is more than 8 digits?  Would it be XXXX-XX-XX-XX?  What are you adding the 5 to?

Comment: Some of the numbers are in the XXXX-XX-XX format from the beginning and others have fewer dashes and characters. I just want to insert a symbol at the nth character.

The addition of 5 was an example of a very sophisticated algorithm ;) It doesnt really matter what math you do. The output format shoiuld have one dash after character 4, and one after character 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you could do a replace with the following:

```
(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d+)
```

to

```
$1-$2-$3
```

Comment: is that in StringOut.replace(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d+) or some other operation?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172861/python-regex-replace). Or a simple google search would suffice.

Comment: Thx, If never used Python/Jython before and the replace method I found was string.replace()